# How to send SMS and number from contacts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hai
  I am new to iphone and i am creating an application. I want to send sms to preconfigured number and also want to from the phonebook also. How can i do this. Please help me.

Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below SO post

[send sms programaticaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819013/send-sms-programaticaly)

[send sms through programming in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772770/send-sms-through-programming-in-iphone)

For AddressBook

[Using Cocoa Touch Tutorial: Extract Address Book Address Values on iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994870/using-cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os)

[how can I access the label of phone number in AddressBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720880/how-can-i-access-the-label-of-phone-number-in-addressbook)

Comment: how to select number from phonebook also?