# sending message to pre configured numbers

Tags: iphone

Hai
    I am developing a new application. In that send a message to pre configured numbers and the user selecting numbers. How it is possible? when then send button is pressed. Please help. Can any give me some Sample code or tutorial.

Thank You

Comment: Take a look at this docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: can we check through the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the below SO post,

[How to send SMS and number from contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483383/how-to-send-sms-and-number-from-contacts/5483492#5483492)

Here is link could help you ...

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html

SMS
To open the SMS application, just use the sms: protocol in your URL:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

You can specify a phone number, **but apparently not a default text for your message:**

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:+12345678901";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: but i want a default msg to give. For that what should do?

Comment: @Akhila : I do'nt think you could do so, plz read my answer carefully you could only launch the application with a pre configured numbers.... Not with the message content ...